# Failed to get composer template data

Tags: facebook, templates

Few of our websites like womens-health.com.my, mens-health.com.my, and elle.my having problem post any article to Facebook. When I test any URLs of these websites in Facebook Debugger, it gave me warning messages said that `Failed to get composer template data.` and `Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed`. I have no idea what causing this as other of our websites are working fine.

Comment: I've removed the "composer-php" tag, because this issue is unrelated to "Composer" (PHP dependency manager). The tag "Facebook" fits.

Comment: Hi Jens, thanks for your reply. Do you mean after you have removed "composer-php" tag will solve my problem. I just tried again to post but still no response and cannot capture the OG Tags.

Comment: I cannot see "Failed to get composer template data" in facebook debugger. But I think you would need to add og:xxx tags to make your page sharing properly.

Answer (score 1):

It's an actual Facebook bug, which is being fixed right now: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/918385908182634/

In summary, you can fix this by making sure that article:author only contains Facebook user IDs or Facebook profile URLs.